# OCaml: Returning Full List after Change to Element

Tags: list, recursion, dictionary, ocaml

## Context:

In [ocaml](/questions/tagged/ocaml), when taking a full `list` in as a parameter, the method `change` is suppose to iterate through the `list`, and if a search is successful for a `variable` in the `list`, then we change that variable's binding to another value. Right now, I have the code **at the bottom** that does everything correctly, except returning the full list.

For clarity sake, this list should be best thought of as a dictionary that contains tuples.

## Question:

How can my expression save the list that is being taken in, and return it, **while iterating through it**? In regards to the identified problem (can be see below), that only part of the list is being returned: Is this a fundamental flaw in the expression, or is this an easy fix? If this is an easy fix, what can be added to throw that in for the final return?

## Code:

```
let rec change key value dict =
  match dict with
    | [] -> [(key, value)] (*Adding to the dictionary*)
    | (a,b) :: dict -> if compare a key = 0 then (a, value)::dict      (*changing value*)
                       else                      change key value dict (*continue search*)
;;
```

**EXAMPLES OF CODE:**

```
# let list = [(1,2);(4,2);(2,1)];;
val list : (int * int) list = [(1, 2); (4, 2); (2, 1)]
# change 2 3 list;;
- : (int * int) list = [(2, 3)]
# change 1 1 list
  ;;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 1); (4, 2); (2, 1)]
# change 4 1 list
  ;;
- : (int * int) list = [(4, 1); (2, 1)]
# change 7 1 list
  ;;
- : (int * int) list = [(7, 1)]
```

## ANSWER:

```
let rec change key value dict =
  match dict with
    | [] -> (key, value)::dict (*Adding to the dictionary*)
    | (a,b) :: dict -> if compare a key = 0 then (a, value)::dict (*changing value*)
                       else (a,b)::change key value dict (*continue search*)
;;
```

If you see the above, in the fifth line, at the else statement, there is an addition of `(a,b)::` which does the recursion in the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to think more like a functional programmer. What I'm trying to say is that you should stop thinking of it as a change to the old list. You should think of it as a whole new list.

In words, you might want to think something like this:

- If the list is empty, the result is empty
- If the list looks like `hd :: tl`, the result depends on what `hd` looks like.
- In particular, if `hd` is something I'm supposed to modify, the result looks like the modified `hd` followed by a modified `tl`.
- But if the head isn't something I'm supposed to modify, the result looks like `hd` followed by a modified `tl`.

If you think this way, the code should be pretty easy to write.

**Update**

It appears that you have some invariants on your dictionary that I didn't take into account. If you know dictionary entries are unique the third case changes to returning a modified `hd` followed by the old `tl`.

If you also want to add the entry if it doesn't appear, the first bullet changes to return a list of your one pair (rather than returning an empty list).

I'm trying to illustrate a way of thinking more functionally (possibly unsuccessfully, but that's what I'm trying :-).

Comment: So, I need should probably delete what I currently have, and start anew? :)

Comment: Code-wise it's just a tiny change. I'm trying to suggest an FP-style way of looking at things that would help for very many problems. But anyway, no need to throw away what you have. You can tweak it. Also, I didn't realize that you want to add the new pair if it's not there. So that's a tiny bit different.

Comment: I agree with your edit, and appreciate the path versus the answer. I'll play with this for a bit!

Comment: Just got it figured out: missing `(a,b)::change num1 num2 dict` ;)